# How to deploy django-q worker with docker?

Tags: django, docker-compose, django-q

Assume this simple docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:  
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

How can i add django-q worker to handle tasks from `web` container?

I could probably build same image with different command such as `python manage.py qcluster` but I dont think this solution si elegant. Could you suggest some approach how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the most easy thing that you can do is to add a new cluster for qcluster.
Something like this:

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:  
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
  djangoq:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py qcluster
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8001"
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Comment: I am new at docker and I am confused... the same port (8000) for both clusters?

Comment: Well it depends on your qcluster setup... It's just an example :) And yes you might probably need to change TCP port of djangoq to be different then web TCP port. :)
I edit the response.
Thanks @DayanneGarcia